# How to pass the password securely to MySQL Client with automation

Tags: mysql, passwords, client, config, stdin

I'm seeking for solution to pass the password securely to MySQL client on *nix platforms while using automated script solution (i.e Bash script).

So far, I had to realize that MySQL ignores password input from stdin at all (still asks for password on terminal, crashes on automation).

The worst, solution using ~/.mylogin.cnf also doesn't work for me, it seems MySQL somehow ignores it at all.

I prefer to not to use the command line -p argument for password to prevent described "all-around" security issues.

--defaults-file and --defaults-extra-file handn't give the solution as well, seems like the password is prompted by client at "all-cost".

Therefore, I'm just running out of solutions for that primitive (at first sight) task!

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you have a password inside the defaults file, it shouldn't prompt for it.

Comment: Indeed, looks like something prevents the client from reading the password from defined sources, I suspect any compile options used for MySQL packages by apt while installed. Could be this one the answer?

Comment: Anything is possible, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Anyway, it seems I clearly stuck with -p argument solution, how badly doesn't it sound. Another way I see is just pass the password to the MySQL like it comes from terminal stream and not stdin stream, still cannot find how it;s possible.

Comment: I use the defaults file all the time. It does work. I don't know how you are invoking the client, but one common issue is that people don't realize that `--defaults-file` must be the **first option on the comand-line**, before `--host` or `--user` or any other option. Also if you use `-p` on the command-line, it will be forced to prompt even if you have defaults in your options files or in .mylogin.cnf.

Comment: Good point about parameters order. And yes, i've almost tried using -p option among with defaults-file since otherwise a receive the connection failure with (PASSWORD:NO) remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to be short in my findings:

First, the solution using `mysql --defaults-extra-file="path/to/file"` is actually worked for me among with `--default-file` option **until it is passed as the first argument** (as well noticed by Bill Karwin here).

Second, usage of `~/mylogin.cnf` also workes fine until **the file access restricted for all users except the current account the MySQL client is running under + file is restricted from execution even by current user (chmod u-x) as well,** possibly treated by MySQL as a threat due to Linux GUI x permission umbrella on many systems (execute permission is enabled for user, group and others by setting one V in GUI for the file). Still this reason is just a suggestion.